# Clojure unable to resolve symbol

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am new to Clojure. I was trying to run this and got cannot find symbol parse-to-dict.

```
(ns noobfile
  (:require '[clojure.string :as str]
            '[noobfile]))

(def my_str "1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533")
(def my_dict (str/split my_str #"\n"))
(defn pasre-to-dict [x] (str ":" x))
(apply parse-to-dict my_dict)
```

The error is given below:

```
CompilerException java.lang.Exception: Found lib name 'clojure.string' containing period with prefix 'quote'.  lib names inside prefix lists must not contain periods, compiling:(/tmp/form-init6237588243498764600.clj:16:1)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: parse-to-dict in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init6237588243498764600.clj:28:1)
```

Comment: You've called it `pasre-to-dict` not `parse-to-dict`.

Comment: also the `str` is shadowed by `clojure.string` alias. Do not alias anything with the name of core function (unless you really know what you're doing)

Comment: @leetwinski no it is not shadowed. This is [common practice](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/86a158d0e0718f5c93f9f2bb71e26bc794e7d58e/src/clj/clojure/core/server.clj#L12).

Answer (score 1):

1. There shouldn't be a quote in the `require` clause.
2. There is no reason to require `noobfile`.
3. You have a typo in `(defn pasre-to-dict [x] (str ":" x))`.
4. Using [`apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) doesn't make sense in this case. You probably want to modify the `parse-to-dict` function depending on what you want to achieve.

So you can continue here:

```
(ns noobfile
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(def my_str "1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
  2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
  3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533")
(def my_dict (str/split my_str #"\n"))
(defn parse-to-dict [x] (str ":" x))
(parse-to-dict my_dict)
```

Please do more research on your own before asking a question next time.

Comment: First down vote ever for me. This seems like a reasonable attempt to try Clojure, and "please do more research" is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is `map` and not `apply`.

```
(map parse-to-dict my_dict)
```

have a read in [clojure docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map)

Answer (score 0):

i would go with something like this:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as cs])

(reduce #(let [[x & xs] (cs/split (cs/trim %2) #"\|")]
           (assoc %1 x xs))
        {}
        (cs/split-lines my_str))

;; => {"1" ("John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"), 
;;     "2" ("Sue Jones" "43 Rose Court Street" "345-7867"), 
;;     "3" ("Fan Yuhong" "165 Happy Lane" "345-4533")}
```

but really you should read some clojure basics before you begin, as everybody suggested.